# Qt custom SLOT of subclass not recognised by CONNECT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-signals, qt-slot

### Background

I am writing a media player application in Qt.  I have subclassed QMediaPlayer and created a new SLOT which is capable of interpreting an int and passing it as qint64 to QMediaPlayer::SetPosition(qint64).

QMediaPlayer::PositionChanged fires a signal to the cslider slider_playback (a horizontal slider subclass).  This makes the slider move as a song is playedback.  There are also some subclassed labels (clabel) which receive signals regarding the song duration and song playback position.

### Problem

The problem i have occurs when I build & run, I receive the following error:

> Starting /home/daniel/DeveloperProjects/build-Player-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/Player...
>
> QObject::connect: No such slot QMediaPlayer::set_playback_position(int) in ../Player/mainwindow.cpp:23
>
> QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'slider_playback')

The slider should be able to control the position of the playback.  The offending line of code is preceeded by a '// Player seek' comment in the file.

I think the error indicates that the base class is being referred to for the SLOT, whereas the slots is actually part ofthe derived class.

Why is this error occuring and what action would resolve the issue?  The slots in my clabel and cslider classes work without issue.  The difference is that those classes have constructors and destructors. I have not implemented a constructor in the QMediaPlayer subclass as I do not want to override the base class constructor.

### cmediaplayer.h (full file)

```
#ifndef CMEDIAPLAYER_H
#define CMEDIAPLAYER_H

#include <QMediaPlayer>
//#include <QObject>

class cmediaplayer : public QMediaPlayer
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void set_playback_position(int);
};

#endif // CMEDIAPLAYER_H
```

### cmediaplayer.cpp (full file)

```
#include "cmediaplayer.h"

void cmediaplayer::set_playback_position(int v) {
    this->setPosition( (qint64)v );
}
```

### mainwindow.h (full file)

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include "cmediaplayer.h"
#include "clabel.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QPalette m_pal;
    QString media_file_str="/usr/share/example-content/Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase/Jenyfa Duncan - Australia.ogg";
    //QMediaPlayer * player ;
    cmediaplayer * player; // My custom type

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_pressed();
    void on_pushButton_released();
    void on_button_playback_clicked();
};
```

### mainwindow.cpp (full file)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //player = new QMediaPlayer;
    player = new cmediaplayer; // My custom type

    // set max time on playback slider
    connect(player, SIGNAL(durationChanged(qint64)), ui->slider_playback, SLOT(set_qint64_max(qint64)));

    // st max time on playback label
    connect(player, SIGNAL(durationChanged(qint64)), ui->label_track_length, SLOT(setIntText(qint64)));

    // set slider playback position
    connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)), ui->label_track_position, SLOT(setIntText(qint64)));


    // Player seek
    connect(ui->slider_playback,
        SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
        player,
        SLOT(set_playback_position(int)));


    // Player volume
    connect(ui->slider_volume,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),player,SLOT(setVolume(int)));
    ui->slider_volume->setValue(50); // set player initial value
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui;
    delete player;
    //delete playlist;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_pressed() {
    m_pal=this->palette().color(QPalette::Background);
    QPalette pal=palette();
    pal.setColor(QPalette::Background,Qt::gray);
    this->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    this->setPalette(pal);

    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(media_file_str));
    player->setPlaybackRate(1);
    player->play();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_released() {
    QPalette pal=m_pal;
    this->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    this->setPalette(pal);
    //player->stop();
}

void MainWindow::on_button_playback_clicked()
{
    //player->play();
}
```

Comment: It seems that at compile time the other line was commented out:     `//QMediaPlayer * player ;
    cmediaplayer * player; // My custom type` And start class names with capital letter (coding convention).

Comment: @AlexanderVX the QMediaPlayer was the original object.  I replaced it with cmedia player which did compiled. I left it there for commenting purpose

Comment: Well, it's encouraging that it compiles for you @eyllanesc

I restarted Qt (again) and now it's complaining:

In function cmediaplayer::cmediaplayer() 

undefined reference to vtable for cmediaplayer

collect2:error: ld returned 1 exit status which has really bamboozled me as I've not changed anything!

Comment: @eyllanesc https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4QUZRlxzP4hUFQ0UkdzWEZCc00

I've got rid of some of the unused stuff in the *.h and *.cpp files to tidy up a bit

Comment: @eyllanesc I've trashed the build file, and recompiled everything and it has cleared the errors i encounterred.  Seems to work now!

Comment: @eyllanesc A few minutes before, I clicked Clear All and the I recompiled.  I actually had to use my filesystem to remove the build file before it would work

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for your help. if you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it as the useful answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt creates a new class that implements the actual connection between the slots and the signals but many times this one is not updated. The classes they refer to have a name similar to **moc_xxx.cpp** and these are created in the build folder.

To force them to update we must click on the **make clean** submenu that is located in the Menu Build of QtCreator, and then **run qmake** in the same menu.

Or you can manually remove the build folder and compile it back

Comment: In this case I had to manually remove the build file using the os file system

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, it could help somebody. I had a similar issue when trying to use a SLOT function in the connect call. Even though the slot was declared and defined in the subclass, the connect function not recognize it, issuing a message which says that the slot function is not part of the base class.

In my case, the problem was that I didn't place the `Q_OBJECT` in the beginning of the class declaration. After that, I had to clean (otherwise, various errors occur in compilation step) and build the project again to had the slot function working properly.

Comment: It is no longer recommended to use the SLOT macro since it has several disadvantages such as the connection is not verified in compile time but in the execution time, I recommend using the new connection syntax: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax. On the other hand it is only necessary to use Q_OBJECT when creating slots, signals, Q_INVOKABLE, Q_PROPERTY, Q_ENUMS, etc. that are generated by the MOC. The problem you point out is classic.